# Python:Can anybody explain me this one line code?

Tags: python

```
print(''.join(map(str,range(1,n+1))))
```

Like what is str doing here ? and how is this outputting in the single line ?i know what map and join does but still i'm not clear with this whole code

Comment: `str` is a function that gets the representation of an object as string. So map transforms every number in `range(1,n+1)` to a string and concatenates it

Comment: The best way to learn how some code like this works is break it down. Try each bit in isolation and see what it does. Also, there's nothing in the least tricky here - try reading the documentation.

Comment: it is basically the same as doing `"".join([str(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)])`, it just uses map to cast each int to str.

Answer (score 4):

```
numbers_one_to_n = range(1,n+1)
numbers_as_strings = map(str, numbers_one_to_n)
numbers_joined_to_single_string = ''.join(numbers_as_strings)
print(numbers_joined_to_single_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(''.join(map(str,range(1,n+1))))
```

You say you know what `map` does?  The documentation says:

```
map(function, iterable, ...)
Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the result.
```

So `str` is the function.  The iterable is the `range` of integers (in Python 3 this is a `range` object`)

`str` returns a string object generated from its argument.

So, `str` is called for each integer in the range.

An alternative to `map` is a *list comprehension*, which some prefer:

```
print(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`''` is a separator, that used between the concatenating elements (strings in a string sequence or characters in a string). For instance:

```
>>> '-'.join(('foo', 'bar'))
'foo-bar'
>>> '-'.join('bar')
'b-a-r'
```

`str` is a type and the function to convert to this type.
So, `map(str, list_of_integers)` converts this list to a list of strings. Because `map` applies the function to each element of input list to get output list.

So, we have the range from 1 to (n + 1), that have been converted to the list of the strings, and then this list have been concatenated with the empty slitter `''`.